# PHP, Wordpress - How can I pass Variables within a File?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I integrated a PHP file in my Wordpress installation with a plugin. I have found out, how I am able to send several variables and posting them to a MySQL database, but I am confused, how  to manipulate my data like this:

```
$web = "http://internal.weddingcenter.at/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/orders.php";
a href="<? echo ''.$web.'?contact='.$daten[id].'' ?>">Rechnung</a>

if ($contact) {


$datum = date('Y-m-d', $date);

$sql_update = "Update wccrm_orders set contacted_date = $datum where id = $contact";
$result = mysql_query($sql_update, $db);
```

}

I never jump into the `if-clause`.

How can this be solved?

Comment: Expecting `$contact` to be auto-populated depends on an old, unsafe, and removed PHP feature called `register_globals`. Instead, you need to access [the `$_GET` superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php), but beware of SQL injection. At a minimum you must call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on that variable. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Answer (score 0):

It has to be :

```
    if($_GET['contact'])
        ...
```

OR You cant try :

```
$contact = $_GET['contact'];
    if($_GET['contact'])
        ...
```

Comment: Hi Folks,thanks a lot. Kunal was correct - if ($_GET...) made the deal. Funny, that a if ($contact) is working on another Webserver I am using...

Comment: You must have done `$contact  = $_GET['contact']` on the page earlier.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Kunal Gupta I can see more problems...

```
if ($_GET['contact']) {

  //Forgot to mention SQL injection prevention...
  //Try preg_replace or mysqli_real_escape_string()

  $datum = preg_replace('[0-9 \/]', '', date('Y-m-d',$date)); //I think that will work
  //OR
  $test = date('Y-m-d', $date);
  $datum = mysqli_real_escape_string($test); //Should also work...

  //You must always place PHP variables in inverted commas
  $sql_update = "UPDATE wccrm_orders SET contacted_date='$datum' WHERE id='$contact'";
  //use MySQLi... It's quicker. Use the variables this way around
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql_update);
}
```

There are still quite a few problems with the code but without fully understanding what data is coming from the previous page or what you intend to do with the data I can only help so much.

Comment: Also one should now move on from mysql to mysqli or an other option. Ironically I still use mysql :P

Comment: @KunalGupta It's still a perfectly fine solution to use... MySQLi is quicker and more efficient, it's not something the end-user would notice on a standard website so it doesn't really matter too much. It's just as easy to use MySQLi and it's easy to change from MySQL to MySQLi... I try to encourage others to use it too.